# Unable to append new result *first* in an existing csv file having old data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a script in python which is able to fetch the title of different posts from a webpage and write them to a csv file. As the site updates it's content very frequently, I like to append the new result first in that csv file where there are already list of old titles available.

I've tried with:

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"

def get_information(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    for title in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        yield title.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        with open("output.csv","a",newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(['posts'])
            for items in get_information(url):
                writer.writerow([items])
                print(items)

        time.sleep(300)
```

The above script which when run twice can append the new results after the old results.

Old data are like:

```
A
F
G
T
```

New data are `W`,`Q`,`U`.

The csv file should look like below when I rerun the script:

```
W
Q
U
A
F
G
T
```

***How can I append the new result first in an existing csv file having old data?***

Comment: From your comment to my answer, it seems that you have an update to make to your question.  What code are you using for the insertion, and how do you have trouble running in a regular interval?

Comment: Lots of new csv files will be there if I keep my script running giving 5 minutes sleep @Prune.

Comment: How will you have lots of new files?  At most, there should be only two existing at a time.

Comment: Check out the edit. If there will always be two files then it is okay.

Comment: When the script runs for the third time, the second csv file will be the one having old data, so the logic you suggested won't be of any use @Prune. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the answer: the final step is to move the new file back to the old file name.  There is no longer any "second csv file".

Comment: As it has been suggested, you would have to either store the old data in memory or use a temporary, second file if the data is too large. An alternative would be to write the data normally, at the end of the file, then when you read it seek to the position where the last entry starts. But that is not easy or reliable in this case, because each entry has arbitrary size, so you would have to guesss its size, seek it at the end of the file, then read and seek until you find a mark. I understand it's not what you're looking for, but you'll have to do what has been suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting data anywhere in a file except at the end requires rewriting the whole thing. To do this without reading its entire contents into memory first, you could create a temporary csv file with the new data in it, append the data from the existing file to that, delete the old file and rename the new one.

Here's and example of what I mean (using a dummy get_information() function to simplify testing).

```
import csv
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python'
csv_filepath = 'updated.csv'

# For testing, create a existing file.
if not os.path.exists(csv_filepath):
    with open(csv_filepath, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([item] for item in 'AFGT')

# Dummy for testing.
def get_information(url):
    for item in 'WQU':
        yield item


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(csv_filepath))  # Get dir of existing file.

    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', newline='', suffix='.csv',
                            dir=folder, delete=False) as newf:
        temp_filename = newf.name  # Save filename.
        # Put new data into the temporary file.
        writer = csv.writer(newf)
        for item in get_information(url):
            writer.writerow([item])
            print([item])

        # Append contents of existing file to new one.
        with open(csv_filepath, 'r', newline='') as oldf:
            reader = csv.reader(oldf)
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow(row)
                print(row)

    os.remove(csv_filepath)  # Delete old file.
    os.rename(temp_filename, csv_filepath)  # Rename temporary file.
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you intend to change the position of every element of the table, you need to read the table into memory and rewrite the entire file, starting with the new elements.

You may find it easier to (1) write the new element to a new file, (2) open the old file and append its contents to the new file, and (3) move the new file to the original (old) file name.

Comment: Your suggestion seemed to work out except for renaming thing. Check out the error the script throws while renaming the new one with old one. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\demo file\demo_script.py", line 36, in <module>
    os.rename("new_output.csv","output.csv")
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'new_output.csv' -> 'output.csv'`

Comment: You failed to post the failing code.  How did you try to replace the old file with the new one?  You need to take that up with your OS.  It *looks* like you tried to do this from Python `os` commands, simply `rename`ing without first deleting the original file.

Comment: Yup -- look at the documentation for `rename`.  Look at the final two lines of `martieau`'s answer.  Also, note that an off-site link is *not* acceptable as part of a Stack Overflow problem.